# Regarding IF or Case statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do something like this:

IF today is "current MM-DD" then all MM-DD between Sept-01 and "Current MM-DD" are Y else N. In all years.

I have many years in my data (i.e 2017-2024)

IF(date = current_date, "I am lost here")

So my expected answer is: If today is Nov-10 then all years (2017-2024) from Sept-1 to Nov-10 is "Y" and the rest is "N"

Comment: what if current_date is before Sept-01 ?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below query.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT date FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-01-01', '2024-12-31')) date
)
SELECT current_date,
       date,
       IF (FORMAT_DATE('%m-%d', date) BETWEEN '09-01' AND FORMAT_DATE('%m-%d', current_date), 'Y', 'N') in_range
  FROM sample_data;
```